# Message: getimagesize-failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php

El error completo que obtengo es:
(Tengo PHP V7.1, Y dicho Script está en una Subcarpeta)

```
Message: getimagesize(http://thekingstim.com/down/down/assets/images/cover.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Filename: controllers/Main.php

Line Number: 40
```

Y:

```
Backtrace:

File: /home/theking2/public_html/down/application/controllers/Main.php
Line: 40
Function: getimagesize
```

Y Este es el codigo del Archivo Main.php (Linea 36 a 41)

```
    $settings = $this->DefaultModel->generalSettings();
    $data['settings'] = $settings;
    $cover = array();
    $coverPath = base_url("assets/images/".$settings['coverImage']);
    $cover['path'] = $coverPath;
    $cover['porperties'] = getimagesize($coverPath);
    $data['cover'] = $cover;
```

Alguien Me Podria ayudar con este Problema? Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando una imagen que no es accesible y si pones `http://thekingstim.com/down/down/assets/images/cover.png` en el navegador sale un **404** :/

Asegurate de que dicha imagen existe en el server.

Ahora mismo no lo recuerdo bien, pero en cualquier caso, el parámetro de **getimagesize** tiene que ser un string por lo que deberías incluir entrecomillado.

Salu2